# How can I use a recipe in Make to run several distinct Makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I inherited a project that has multiple top level Makefiles, one for each very-similar platform that the firmware image runs on.  They have names like:

Makefile.apple.mak
Makefile.banana.mak
...

So every time I want to build a specific image, I run the command
Make -f Makefile.apple.mak  // default is release

Much of the code is shared between the different images that get built.  A problem with doing this is that sometimes when a change is made that compiles and works for the apple platform, it breaks the banana platform.  There is a whole mess of #ifdefs that conditionally include or exclude code based on the platform specified by the Makefile.  I know, it's a mess and badly in need of a refactor (did I mention I inherited this?)

In order to easily build all of the firmware images after making a change and declaring it good on one platform, I want to have a wrapping Makefile that invokes a build of one or all of the available firmware images.

I am currently looking at this brute-force approach.  I know there's got to be a more efficient way to do this.  I also don't know offhand how to pass additional arguments to this outer Makefile (i.e. make apple debug) if that is possible.  Any help is appreciated.

```
.PHONY: all
all: cleanall releaseall

.PHONY: cleanall
cleanall:
    make -f Makefile.apple.mak clean    # Can I instead call apple target with an arg?
    make -f Makefile.banana.mak clean   # Can I instead call banana target with an arg?

.PHONY: releaseall
releaseall:
    make -f Makefile.apple.mak
    make -f Makefile.banana.mak

.PHONY: apple
apple:
    make -f Makefile.apple.mak # how do I pass in the <clean | debug | release> args?

.PHONY: banana
banana:
    make -f Makefile.banana.mak # how do I pass in ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(BTW, you never want to use `make` to invoke a recursive make.  Always use `$(MAKE)`)

The way to do this is construct target names encoding the image and the target for that image you want to build.  Then you can use make prerequisites.

So, for example, you can do something like this:

```
IMAGES := apple banana ...

all: cleanall releaseall

cleanall: $(IMAGES:%=%.clean)
releaseall: $(IMAGES)

$(IMAGES):
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.$@.mak

$(IMAGES:%=%.clean):
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.$(basename $@).mak clean

.PHONY: all cleanall releaseall $(IMAGES) $(IMAGES:%=%.clean)
```

This also lets you run `make apple.clean` to clean just the `apple` directory, or whatever.

You can add more targets like `debug`, etc. as well.

Comment: This is very elegant and answers my question about passing arguments to the wrapping makefile.  Thanks!